# How to input URLs in CiviCRM fields (custom fields or standard fields) so that they're clickable

Tags: urls

Does anyone know if this is possible? I want to save a URL in a CiviCRM field so that it's clickable when the field content is displayed eg in a report, or just in a normal CiviCRM page view.

Example: store the URL for a page on a contact's website, so that when I display the contact record, the website URL appears as a clickable link. I suspect it must be possible, but can't work out how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There two ways a field which can be used as link.

1. **Contact's website field**
   This is field is available for Contact of all type i.e Individual, Org etc. on new contact form or can also be added to profile.

[image]

2. **Custom field of type link**
   CiviCRM provides custom fields for different type. You can use custom field of type **link** if you want it to be used as link as it provides validation.

[image]

HTH

Pradeep